# Sinon stub is not working in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, stub

I am trying to use sinon stub to test my function by creating mock values for IF statement is working as it is described in the testFunction

In one of the file myFunction.js I have functions like

```
function testFunction() {
  var job = this.win.get.value1   //test
  var job1 = this.win.get.value2 // test1
  if(job === 'test' && job1 === 'test1') {
    return true;
  }
    return false; 
}
```

and I am trying to test testFunction using karma and I tried to stub test function using sinon stub like this

```
it('should test my function', function(done) {
  var stub = sinon.stub(myFunction,'job','job1').returns('test','test1');
  myFunction.testFunction('test', function(err, decodedPayload) {
    decodedPayload.should.equal(true);
    done();
  });
});
```

Can anybody tell me where i am doing the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `sinon.stub` incorrectly. You need to make two calls to `sinon.stub`, one for each method of `myFunction` that you want to stub.

```
it('should test my function', function(done) {
  sinon.stub(myFunction,'job').returns('test');
  sinon.stub(myFunction,'job1').returns('test1');
  myFunction.testFunction('test', function(err, decodedPayload) {
    decodedPayload.should.equal(true);
    done();
  });
});
```

→ [See Sinon documentation](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.3.0/stubs/)

Comment: These two are not functions but two values in the variable and is this the right way to stub the values?

Comment: this above answer is giving  an error "attemted to wrap undefined property of job as function"